# Exporting user's input to SharePoint list through Power Virtual Agents

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate, flow, chatbot

Currently I'm working on task that demands creating a chatbot, that will save user input in SharePoint list. Bot has to ask user for details like First Name, Last Name, Date of birth etc. and after collecting this data, Bot has to save these inputs in specific columns in SP list.

Is there any option in Power Virtual Agents to complete it? Or I have to use Power Automate flow and attach it to PVA?

*Bot has to be run via Microsoft Teams Conversation.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use Power Automate flow to add data inside the SharePoint list. You can use **Create item** action in flow to add data to SharePoint list.

Refer documentation: [SharePoint connector actions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/sharepointonline/#actions)

**Similar thread**: [Power virtual agent - insert data in SharePoint list and then display this data](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/General/Power-virtual-agent-insert-data-in-sharepoint-list-and-then/td-p/619240)

Comment: Hi @Yarensky, does this help you in any way? If yes, please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily. It also removes this question from "Unanswered questions" list.